# Что такое заглушка?

Tags: тестирование, терминология

Что такое заглушка в тестировании и для чего она нужна?
Например: заглушка базы данных.

Comment: Если говорить о загрушке БД, то это эмуляция успешных (а может и нет) запросов в бд. Это нужно для тестирования кода без использования базы данных. Если вы тестируете, например, формирование строки для вставки в бд, то сама бд вам не нужна.

Comment: Как я понял по гуглу заглушка -- это эмуляция некоторого элемента системы, с заданными свойствами. То есть вместо отсутсвующей БД можно написать просто заглушку которая каждый раз по запросу будет выдавать нужные данные, верно?

Comment: я на работе часто пишу заглушки для эмуляции информационных систем банков-партнеров (т.е. ловлю запросы уходящие с нашей информационной системы, произвожу с входными параметрами какие-либо действия и отправляю ответ), удобно проверять интеграцию со своей стороны вне зависимости от работоспособности тестового окружение банка, а оно чаще всего лежит

Comment: @nick_gabpe Да, верно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заглушка - это некая сущность, которая заменяет реальную, работа которой в данном случае не важна. На самом деле это очень полезная штука, так как начинающие программисты часто пытаются реализовать и отладить сразу все компоненты, в результате чего получается запутаный код, который еле работает по принципу "нос вылез - хвост увяз".

Типичный пример - отладка какого-то алгоритма, работающего с поступающими снаружи данными. А если предполагается ввод руками, то это ещё и отягощает процесс отладки ненужными действиями. Вместо того, чтобы сразу писать ввод, проще взять какой-то заранее готовый набор данных (написать заглушку, которая его отдаёт).  И только после отладки основных частей программы превратить заглушку в реальный ввод.

В идеале заглушками могут быть вообще все сущности, которые не имеют никакого отношения к отлаживаемому в данный момент коду, и заменяться по мере необходимости по схеме "отладил кусок - заменил одну заглушку на код, отладил бывшую заглушку - приступаем к следующей", и т.д.

Comment: в последнем случае это уже напоминает тест-модули (test units). Отличие будет только в том что эти модули могут использоваться повторно для тестирования изменений, внесенный в код других модулей в процессе поддежки ПО

Answer (score 3):

[Stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub) это объект, который симулирует поведение замещаемого им объекта. Пример на C#:

```
interface IDatabaseContext
{
   List<string> GetItems();
}
```

Реализация:

```
class DatabaseContext : IDatabaseContext
{
   public List<string> GetItems()
   {
    ...работа с базой данных
   }
}
```

Чтобы в тестировании объектов, которые используют данную зависимость(интерфейс) не работать с реальной базой данных, можно создать *объект-заглушку*. Данная заглушка будет возвращать заранее описанные данные, и для пользователей-объектов интерфейса разницы никакой не будет, так как они получат ожидаемые данные, но при этом не будет зависимости от реальной базы данных. В этом и плюс.

```
class StubContext : IDatabaseContext
{
    public List<string> GetItems()
    {
       return new List<string>(){"temp1","temp2"};
    }
}
```